react-facebook-login giving error: "It looks like this app isn't available, please contact..."
I am trying to use react-facebook-login for facebook login in my nextjs app. I have created app on meta for developers.
Below is my code:
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

const handleFacebookCallback = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
}

<FacebookLogin
    appId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID}
    autoLoad={true}  
    fields="name, email, picture"
    scope="public_profile,email"
    textButton="Connect"
    cssClass="px-3 py-1 bg-blue-100 text-blue-600 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-200 transition-colors focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
    callback={handleFacebookCallback}
/>

Permissions like public_profile and email is enabled in app with advanced access.
I have used ngrok to host the app, and added that in domain of app, also i have made my facebook app live, but still i am getting same error.
